# Sort template <p-column> in primeng - angular 2

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am trying to sort the auto-increment template column in primeng but it doesn't work without having to specify the `[field]` (I'm not sure what should field be assigned to incase of rowIndex)

```
<p-column header="#" [sortable]="true">
    <template let-index="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
        <span>{{index+1}}</span>
    </template>
</p-column>
```

This displays the auto-increment based on the column index but doesn't sort the column.

Comment: Looking for the similar info myself.

Comment: Strange, their documentation is missing a lot of things!